# Unicast forwarding in RBVT-P routing protocol

Tags: routing, ad-hoc-wireless

As known, Road-based using Vehicular Traffic Proactive routing (RBVT-P) is an unicast algorithm whose uses CPs (Connectivity Packets) for route discovery

The confusion here is that CPs are sent in Unicast mode while some references said that it is sent to all nodes witch corresponds to broadcast mode

Thanks for answering,